# How to send my MySQL data with PHP code to morris-data.js?

Tags: php, mysql, morris.js

I got a problem how to make morris chart with data from MySQL database. I have made a php code with output like how JSON template can accepted to morris-data.js.

Here's my php code name cobaJson.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<?php
include_once("koneksi.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM data_graph ORDER BY x ASC";
$result = mysql_query( $query );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
{  
    $prefix = '';
    echo "[<br />";
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
    {
        echo $prefix . " {<br />";
        echo '  x: ' . $row['x'] . ',' . "<br />";
        echo '  y: ' . $row['y'] . ',' . "<br />";
        echo '  z: ' . $row['z'] . ',' . "<br />";
        echo '  a: ' . $row['a'] . '' . "<br />";
        echo " }";
        $prefix = ",<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />]";
}
?>
```

And here's the output :

> [ { x: 2012, y: 11, z: 6, a: 9 }, { x: 2014, y: 3, z: 3, a: 1 }, { x:
>   2015, y: 4, z: 7, a: 9 } ]

And I try to send this php code to my morris-data.js :

```
    $(function() {
var json = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': 'cobaJson.php',
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })
    ();


    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'morris-bar-chart',
        data: json,
        xkey: 'x',
        ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
        labels: ['Series A', 'Series B', 'Series B'],
        hideHover: 'auto',
        resize: true
    });

});
```

But it still not work, anyone can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In you cobaJson.php file, you should create a clean JSON object with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) as follows :

```
$array = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
{
    array_push(
        $array,
        array(
             'x' => $row['x'],
             'y' => $row['y'],
             'z' => $row['z'],
             'a' => $row['a']
        )
    );
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Edit:

Since you said your json output from the php is ok, the issue should be located in your js file.

Add error function in your ajax object, just after success as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'cobaJson.php',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(
            'status:' + XMLHttpRequest.status +
            ', status text: ' + XMLHttpRequest.statusText
          );
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

and look at your console.

Comment: okay NimS, it works to make my MySQL data to be a JSON object. And next, what should I do to send this JSON object to morris-data.js? Sorry, I still a newbie on using morris chart.

Comment: You just need to get the JSON object from your ajax call like you did.

Comment: I have tried using my ajax calling, but still not working. Are there any mistakes code on my js? I mean, the chart still can't appear, so assume if still there're some problems on my js, perhaps you can explain me my mistake?

Comment: What is the value of data in the success function of your ajax call ?
Did you try to fill the Morris.bar object with the output you gave in example? Does it work? Any console error?

Comment: After I try use console, there's no output data. According the php value output, there's no mistake for json template. But when I call my php file to morris-data, it's unreadable. Why can it happen?

Comment: The console from your debugging code, it said : "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/javascript". How about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have Closed the function in a Unexpected Way.

```
$(function() {
var json = (function () {
        var json = null;
        $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url': 'cobaJson.php',
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) {
                json = data;
            }
        });
        return json;
    })
    ();
```

Change your last two lines into:

```
});
```

Hope It will Help You.